# Coreplot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex on touch up

Tags: ios, core-plot, touch-event

Is there  way to only get `plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex` on touchup on iOS?

I've got panning turned on and trying to pan where there are plot symbols leads to a really bad experience because `plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex` is being called on `touchesBegan` so the `touchesMoved` or something is cancelled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've been working on the event handling recently on the [release-2.0](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/tree/release-2.0) branch. We added touch down and touch up events for each item that has a "wasSelected" delegate method (plots, axes, and legends). The "wasSelected" methods now fire only if the down and up events occur on the same element. You can still scroll as long as the delegate does not implement the touch down methods.

Comment: Cool! So might as well go ahead and jump onto 2.0?

Comment: You can, although be aware there may be more API changes (like the event handling mentioned above) that might require updates in your code before the final release.

Comment: Is there any documentation about API changes for 2.0 yet? :)

Comment: Nothing posted on the web, but you can build your own from the source using Doxygen as usual (build the "Documentation" target in either the Mac or iOS framework project to build a docset and install it in Xcode).

Comment: I have the same problem. When do you plan on releasing 2.0? Whould like to make a static library install, and it doesnt seem possible with 2.0 yet.

Comment: There's no schedule for the release, but probably several months before it's ready. In the mean time, you can build your own with the "Universal Library" target in the iOS Core Plot project.